# Team foundation server 2008 refresh issues

Tags: visual-studio-2008, tfs

I've changed the areas/iterations in vnc and added work items in web access. When I access TFS from VS2008 at home, it shows 0 results for the same query, and iterations shows only one item in the drop down, areas show the old items.

I am stumped! How do I "clean the cache" or refresh? Even though I've disconnected/reconnected and refreshed everything!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can invalidate the cache across all clients by running the following from a VS command prompt on a client machine:

```
witfields rebuildcache /s:MyTfsServer
```

Also, you can clear your local cache by deleting the contents of:

`%UserProfile%\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\2.0\Cache`